# Static Frame Around Page Which Changes Colors As Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a design which is difficult to describe, I've spent hours googling it and found nothing.  The design basically uses a fixed border frame which always stays on the page while the content scrolls through it, with multiple full viewport "slides" stacked vertically.  Each slide has a different background image which is fixed for the parallax effect with background-size:cover as well.  As you scroll down through the content to the next slide, the border color should change with the content to work with the background image of the next slide.  So essentially the side borders will need to be two colors at the same time or have one covering the other.  The attached images should make things more clear.

What I have to start with is this content arranged in what I'm calling slides: http://jsfiddle.net/4wtRv/

**HTML**

```
    <section class="dark" style="background:url('http://www.mccullagh.org/db9/10d-2/new-york-city-at-night.jpg') no-repeat fixed;background-size:cover;">
        <div class="brdr_out">
            <div class="brdr_in">
                <div class="content" style="height:10em;margin-top:-5em;">
                    <div class="title1">TITLE 1</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="light" style="background:url('http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/004/cache/african-elephant_435_600x450.jpg') no-repeat fixed;background-size:cover;">
        <div class="brdr_out">
            <div class="brdr_in">
                <div class="content" style="height:10em;margin-top:-5em;">
                    <div class="title2">Title 2</div>
                    <div class="title3">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html
{
    height: 100%;
}
body
{
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
}
.brdr_in, .brdr_out
{
    bottom: 0;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.brdr_in
{
    margin: .25em;
    padding: 1em;
}
.brdr_out
{
    margin: 1em;
    padding: .25em;
}
.clr1, .dark
{
    color: #fff;
}
.clr2, .light
{
    color: #000;
}
.dark .brdr_in
{
    border: 3px solid #d5d7a1;
}
.dark .brdr_out
{
    border: 5px solid #d5d7a1;
}
.light .brdr_in
{
    border: 3px solid #000;
}
.light .brdr_out
{
    border: 5px solid #000;
}
section
{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
section .content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
.title1, .title2
{
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: .25em;
    line-height: 1.875em;
    padding-bottom: .8em;
}
.title2
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4a4639;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
```

But the tricky part is to make it look like this when you scroll:
[image]

Also, the text needs to be hidden in the margins outside of the frame.

Your help is much appreciated!  This was much more difficult than I anticipated when I told the designer I could do it.  Javascript and any of it's libraries are fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be difficult to split the frame into two colors. The easiest way i can imagine is to make two copies of the frame. Give both a fixed position with one top:0, the other bottom:0, and adjust the heights of both as you scroll so they meet precisely in the middle.

Another solution, that's not to your spec, but may look better, is to fade the border color from one slide to the next. You will need a color interpolation function, a list of slide colors in JavaScript, and a scroll handler function that determines which slide is visible and the distance scrolled to the next slide. Something kind of like this (assuming Jquery, and 1000px slides):

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var slide_distance = window.scrollY / 1000, slide = Math.floor(slide_distance)
    var color = color_interp(slide_colors[slide], slide_colors[slide + 1], slide_distance - slide)
    $('#border').css('color', color)
})
```

Comment: Awesome!  I got it to work using this method of fixed positioning and adjusting top and bottom.  Thanks so much!  Will post sample code below in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rough sample code which solved this.  I have to have each border piece be a separate div so it doesn't cover the text, links, etc.  To block the text when scrolling above and below the frame I add an element which displays the same background image with a higher z-index so it covers the portion outside the frame.

**HTML**

```
    <section class="dark" style="background:url('http://www.mccullagh.org/db9/10d-2/new-york-city-at-night.jpg') no-repeat fixed;background-size:cover;">
        <div class="content" style="height:10em;margin-top:-5em;">
            <div class="title1">TITLE 1</div>
        </div>
   </section>
   <section class="light" style="background:url('http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/004/cache/african-elephant_435_600x450.jpg') no-repeat fixed;background-size:cover;">
        <div class="content" style="height:10em;margin-top:-5em;padding:0 20%;width:60%">
            <div class="title2">Title 2</div>
            <div class="title3">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </div>
        </div>
   </section>

    <div id="top" style="background:url('http://www.mccullagh.org/db9/10d-2/new-york-city-at-night.jpg') no-repeat fixed;background-size:cover;display:none;height:24px;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;z-index:3;"></div>
    <div id="bottom" style="background:url('http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/004/cache/african-elephant_435_600x450.jpg') no-repeat fixed;background-size:cover;display:none;height:24px;position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;z-index:3;"></div>

    <div class="brdr_out">
        <div class="dark">
            <div class="top"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
            <div class="left"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="light">
            <div class="top"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
            <div class="left"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brdr_in">
        <div class="dark">
            <div class="top"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
            <div class="left"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="light">
            <div class="top"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
            <div class="left"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html
{
    height: 100%;
}
body
{
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
}
.clr1, .dark
{
    color: #fff;
}
.clr2, .light
{
    color: #000;
}
section
{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
section .content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
.title1, .title2
{
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: .25em;
    line-height: 1.875em;
    padding-bottom: .8em;
}
.title2
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4a4639;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}

/*The Frame Styles*/
.brdr_in .bottom
{
    bottom: 24px;
}
.brdr_in .bottom, .brdr_in .top
{
    height: 3px;
    left: 24px;
    right: 24px;
}
.brdr_in .dark div, .brdr_out .dark div
{
    background-color: #e4d7b0;
}
.brdr_in div, .brdr_out div
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
}
.brdr_in .left
{
    left: 24px;
}
.brdr_in .left, .brdr_in .right
{
    bottom: 24px;
    top: 24px;
    width: 3px;
}
.brdr_in .light div, .brdr_out .light div
{
    background-color: #434345;
}
.brdr_in .right
{
    right: 24px;
}
.brdr_in .top
{
    top: 24px;
}
.brdr_out .bottom
{
    bottom: 15px;
}
.brdr_out .bottom, .brdr_out .top
{
    height: 5px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
}
.brdr_out .left
{
    left: 15px;
}
.brdr_out .left, .brdr_out .right
{
    bottom: 15px;
    top: 15px;
    width: 5px;
}
.brdr_out .right
{
    right: 15px;
}
.brdr_out .top
{
    top: 15px;
}
```

**JS**

```
       function borders() {
            var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
            var scrollY = window.scrollY;
            var distance = viewportHeight - scrollY;

            //Once we start scrolling, the top border of the next slide needs to be hidden so it doesn't appear over content
            if (scrollY >= 0) {
                $('.light .top').css('display', 'none');
            }
            if (scrollY < 27) {
                $('.brdr_in .light .bottom').css('display', 'none');
            }
            else {
                $('.brdr_in .light .bottom').css('display', 'block');
            }
            if (scrollY < 20) {
                $('.brdr_out .light .bottom').css('display', 'none');
            }
            else {
                $('.brdr_out .light .bottom').css('display', 'block');
            }

            var outerTop = distance;
            var innerTop = distance;

            //We've scrolled enough so that the top of the bottom slide reaches the top of the viewport, need to add top border back in
            if (outerTop < 15) {
                $('.brdr_out .light .top').css('display', 'block');
                outerTop = 15;
            }
            if (innerTop < 24) {
                $('.brdr_in .light .top').css('display', 'block');
                innerTop = 24;
            }

            $('.brdr_out .light .left, .brdr_out .light .right').css('top', outerTop);
            $('.brdr_in .light  .left, .brdr_in .light .right').css('top', innerTop);


            //Add the background image to top/bottom to hide the text as it scrolls under/above it
            if ($('#light .brdr_out').css('border-top-width') == '0px') {
                $('#top').css('display', 'block');
            }
            else {
                $('#top').css('display', 'none');
            }
            if (scrollY > 24) {
                $('#bottom').css('display', 'block');
            }
            else {
                $('#bottom').css('display', 'none');
            }
       }

       $(window).load(function () {
            borders();
       });

       $(window).scroll(function () {
            borders();
        });
```